# Two Calendar alerts not working since iOS 9 update

Tags: calendar, ios, alert

Since the iOS 9.0.x update, I can't set two different alerts on calendar entries.

Whatever I put in for the first or second alert overwrites both time periods.

Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this issue on iOS 9.0.2, and these steps worked for me:

1. Tap "Second Alert"
2. Set it to "None" (at the top)
3. Tap "Second Alert" again
4. Set it to the desired time.

Comment: Great workaround for people that aren't ready to jump to iOS 9.1 yet.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... First alert: 1 day, then set second alert to none, then save, then set second alert to 1 hour, and the first alert is replaced with the second alert, and the second alert is now 1 day. Obviously, the second alert should always be closer to the event than the first alert.

Comment: @Redtopia Updating iOS should fix this problem.

Comment: I'm all updated, but it may just be confusing because the second alert might be the first one to go off. I read somewhere that the first alert is the closest one to the event.

Comment: oh, it's just switching them? that's not a bug. This question is asking about a bug when they both become one day.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed on iOS 9.1 for me. Do a backup just in case your upgrade goes south, but my upgrades were all 15 minutes of waiting during reboots once the download was done.