# Problem with alert setting on Iphone since 9.0.1 update

Tags: ios, calendar

Problem with calendar alerts since I updated to IOS 9.0.1- When I enter or edit an event in Calendar I was getting a problem where when you selected a first alert (say 1 day before) then selected a second alert (say 2 hours before) they would sometimes switch order. You could then select them again and they would be stay in the correct order. Now when you choose a second alert time it becomes the time for both alerts and there is no way to correct them. I tried with the default alerts set to None and to 1 Day doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Same on 9.0.2? This may be related - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211913/two-calendar-alerts-not-working-since-ios-9-update

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this issue on iOS 9.0.2, and these steps worked for me:

1. Tap "Second Alert"
2. Set it to "None" (at the top)
3. Tap "Second Alert" again
4. Set it to the desired time.